# How do I get the tadtone located under the lilypad?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

> **Beware of spoilers.**

I'm currently in Flooded Faron Woods, collecting the tadtone pieces in order to get the Water Dragon's piece of the Song of the Hero. I've collected all of the pieces save one. Near the entrance to the first dungeon in Faron Woods, there is a lilypad containing a tadtone. I'm unable to get it. I've tried flipping it over with my whip, jumping on it from another lilypad, smashing into it, and just about anything else I can think of, however nothing has proved successful.

On the map below, the tadtone and lilypad is located at the "1", on the map below:

[image]
(image source: http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14/Walkthrough/16/MapFaronTadtones.jpg)

How do I get my hands on this last tadtone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to get that tadtone, you need to flip that lilypad over.  The spiky side is down in the water so you won't be able to use your whip on it.  So if you remember what happened in the **Ancient Cistern** with the lilypads, to flip it, you need to jump on it from high above.  The only way you'll be able to jump on it with a significant enough height would be from the great tree.

It should be pretty obvious where to jump from.  When you climb the tree, there will be a part of the platform jutting out in the direction of that lilypad.  Go to the end (and make sure you're facing in the direction of the pad) and jump down.  You should be able to land on the lilypad, flipping it over and releasing the tadtone.

Comment: Wow how did that sneak by me?!

Answer (score 3):

In order to get these, you have to remember how the lilypads worked in the Ancient Cistern.

You have to go back inside the tree, then exit back out to the branches outside.  Once there, you can climb up the tree until you reach what looks like a ramp (which wasn't used your first time through here).

Jump off the ramp onto the lilypad to flip it over.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you just need to Clawshot onto the 2 Peahats from a nearby (bigger) lilypad, then run further up the tree and where there's butterflies you need to jump down to land on the lilypad to flip it over.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much easier.